# Use linq between condition to get value from List

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, arraylist

I have a list that contains 2 records. I need to get value based on the condition in Linq C#. Currently, the below condition is getting both 2 names instead of 1.

**List Data**

```
var groups = new List<Entry>{
            new Entry{
                Name = "Group1",
                StartFrom = 73200,
                End = 73400
            },
            new Entry {
                Name = "Group2",
                StartFrom = 73007,
                End = 73509
            }
        };
```

**Code 1**

```
int value = 73201

string name = Groups.SingleOrDefault(x => (x.StartFrom <= value && x.End>= value )).Name;

Console.WriteLine(name);
//Output should be Group1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your question. It has a low quality and is somehow unclear. What is your goal & difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) & https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, i mean am getting both names instead of 1.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, filter works fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tzrl0d

Comment: @SudheerReddy, its working just fine. Can you point out the part where you are getting both names?

Comment: @SudheerReddy use share in dotnetfiddle to get the new code :)

Comment: @Knoop I just edited my question. Please check

Comment: @Sajid https://dotnetfiddle.net/pSsbOv

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Please check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qy5MaU

Comment: @Knoop Please check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qy5MaU

Comment: @SudheerReddy it's normal, `73200` and `73007` are lower than `73201`, so will renturns more than one, exception thronwn.

Comment: @Sajid How can we solve this?

Comment: @SudheerReddy you seem to have omitted a lot of logic you expect this to have and then expect us to magically understand that logic. What are the rules that determine which entry you want when multiple pass the filter? If you don't tell us exactly what behaviour you want, it's impossible for us to help you

Comment: @Sajid Ok Understand. The problem is with the Data. I will raise the issue with the DB team.

Comment: @Knoop Understand Anoop. The problem is with Data. The issue is fixed. Logic is correct. Data is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SingleOrDefault will throw an exception when more than one results get returned.

[Enumerable.SingleOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=net-5.0)

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

You can try to use FirstOrDefault which will not mind if there are more than one result, it will return the top 1 in the results

Comment: Can we sure that the FirstOrDefault value will be correct?

Comment: It will be as correct as your where expression. Normally you would add a OrderBy or OrderByDescending to either get the first record or the last record.

Answer (score 1):

<del>I think this may work.</del>
This only works if there is no intersection between the StartFrom and End!

```
string name = groups.Where(x => (x.StartFrom <= value && x.End >= value)).FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Correction because I didn't see that the range of group 1 was inside the range of group 2.

```
string name = groups.Where(x => (x.StartFrom <= value && x.End >= value)).OrderByDescending(x => x.StartFrom).FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Comment: This one does not work if the data is not in sequence. https://dotnetfiddle.net/GjuzVB

Comment: You are right, I overlooked the fact that group 1 is inside the range of group 2, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem. the issue is with Data.